# Why is my Express error handler not being called after linting my code?

Tags: express, error-handling, eslint, middleware

I have an Express app with a custom error handler.

```js
app.use((err: Error, _req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  console.log(err)

  // ...send back a well formatted JSON error
}
```

However, when I run my tests, I have a few that intentionally cause an error but the error handler is never called. Further, I can see the errors bubbling up in the test runner.

This all started when I installed ESLint and corrected any linting issues, including some on this error handler.

Why is the error handler not being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important part about an error handler in Express is that it must have four arguments (err, req, res, next) to distinguish it from normal request handlers that have three (req, res, next). This is documented [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#:%7E:text=except%20error%2Dhandling%20functions%20have%20four%20arguments%20instead%20of%20three).

The problem was that ESLint complains when you have unused arguments. In this case, both `req` and `next` are not used in the handler. I have a special rule that let's me prefix unused arguments with an underscore to indicate that they're unused but necessary, hence `_req`. However, I completely removed `next` since you can do this on a normal function. However, this changed the number of arguments.

The solution was to leave `next` with an underscore prefix.

```js
app.use((err: Error, _req: express.Request, res: express.Response, _next: express.NextFunction) => {
```